# Why are you able to use the global keyword inside a function when the global variable doesn't exist in PHP?

Tags: php, function, global-variables, global, keyword

In PHP, I have been researching trying to understand about global variables, superglobals, the global keyword, variable scope etc... I do not understand all of it, but I was just trying to create and run different code to try and figure out how it all works.

I wrote this simple code:

```
<?php

function sample() {
    global $x;
    echo $x = "hello world ";
}

sample();

?>
```

The result is:

hello world

Why is the global keyword working for the $x variable when I never created a $x global variable to begin with?

Any feedback is appreciated - If you can, please explain it as simple as possible - Thank you

Comment: *"I never created a $x global variable"* you did by typing `global $x;` Check this [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a2efa429f826475a3abed3cdbb96be40ebf4841)

Comment: `global $x` in a function is equivalent to `$x =& $GLOBALS['x']` - you're creating a reference to a variable that, when modified, also modifies a copy in global scope. Yes, even if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Cid Thank you for your response! I did not realize I could create a global variable within a function with the global keyword - I thought it had to be in the global scope first before accessing it within the function.

Comment: @iainn Thank you for your response! So I'm referencing a global variable before it exists?